# How to make sure shared variables are thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm facing similar problem:

```
DemoVar = 100 #### or whatever

def DemoMultiThreadMethod(mode):
    DemoRLock.acquire()

    DemoVar = 0 #### or random value
    ...
    Other resources which do not support multi-threaded access

    if mode == 0:
        do A with DemoVar

    elif mode == 1:
        do B with DemoVar
    ...

    DemoRLock.release()

...

def DecideAfterDemo(self):
    NewThread = threading.Thread(target = DemoMultiThreadMethod, args = (RandomMode, ))
    NewThread.start()

    NewThread.join()

    Result = DemoVar

    if Result == SpecificValue:
        Do something
    else:
        Do another
    ...

...

def SpawnThreads(self): 
    #### hundreds of DecideAfterDemo running
    Counter = 0

    while Counter < 1000:
        SpawnAThread = threading.Thread(target = DecideAfterDemo, args = ())
        SpawnAThread.Start()

...
```

How can I make sure it's safe to run `Result = DemoVar`?

I mean if there are tons of locked `DemoMultiThreadMethod`s that are waiting to be processed, you don't really know which one of `DemoVar = 0 #### or random value` and `Result = DemoVar` would run first since both of them are atomic operation(correct me if I'm wrong), which means `Result = DemoVar` might not be safe if there're too many threads in the pool. The solution I can think of is to add `time.sleep(0.01)` after `DemoRLock.acquire()` to make sure `Result = DemoVar` runs first, but this would lose some productivity. Any better idea?

Comment: I'm having problems understanding your setting here. If for instance I have a for-loop which runs `DecideAfterDemo` method 100 times, they don't run in parallel because of `NewThread.join()`. If you have some alternative method of running the threads in parallel, could you give your code for that as well?

Comment: @jsalonen: In `SpawnThreads` tons of `DecideAfterDemo` runs as thread, but because of `NewThread.join()` at some point lots of `DecideAfterDemo` would be like running in parallel

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It now makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is send some value (DemoVar) from DemoMultiThreadMethod to DecideAfterDemo. While you could use some message passing library, the easiest way would be to define the threading class...something like this (untested):

```
class DemoMultiThread(threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self, mode):
         self.mode = mode
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)
     def run(run):
         mode = self.mode
         DemoRLock.acquire()
         ...
         self.result = DemoVar
         DemoRLock.release()

def DecideAfterDemo(self):
     NewThread = DemoMultiThread(mode)
     NewThread.start()
     NewThread.join()
     Result = NewThread.result
     ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Now every time when I try to exchange/share information with multiple threads, I would immediately go to `Queue` module, it's more convenient.